# TeamCity deploy to Tomcat with Ant fails

Tags: ant, teamcity, ant-contrib

I'm running TeamCity 7 on Ubuntu 12, and I'm trying to deploy a war file to a tomcat server on machine with IP x using Ant.
The thing is - this worked on a different machine with TeamCity 7, and the only thing I've changed is the machine (moved to Ubuntu running on KVM), and the TC version (upgrade).

1. I've set ANT_HOME to the correct location, and I see the TC is using it in the build log:
   ... -Dant.home=/usr/share/ant ...
2. I've added the following jars to my ANT_HOME/lib:
   catalina-ant, tomcat-coyote, tomcat-juli, tomcat-util
3. The build is running on an agent which has the default Ant settings
4. My ant file looks like this:

> ```
> <target name="deploy.to.server">
>     <property name="port" value="${tomcat.port}"/>
>     <property name="tomcat.manager" value="manager/text"/>
>     <property name="url" value="http://${tomcat.server}:${port}/${tomcat.manager}"/>
>     <property name="path" value="/${server.name}"/>
>
>     <echo message="Deploying application to ${url}"/>
>
>     <antcall target="undeploy.from.tomcat"/>
>     <sleep seconds="3"/>
>     <antcall target="deploy.to.tomcat"/>
> </target>
>
> <taskdef name="deploy"    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>
> <taskdef name="undeploy"  classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask"/>
>
> <target name="deploy.to.tomcat" description="Install web application">
>     <deploy url="${url}" username="${username}" password="${password}"
>             path="${path}" war="${work.dir}/${path}.war"/>
> </target>
>
> <target name="undeploy.from.tomcat" description="Remove web application">
>     <undeploy url="${url}" username="${username}" password="${password}"
>             path="${path}"/>
> </target>
> ```

I've got this in the TC log:

```
[Step 1/2] Starting: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Dagent.home.dir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent -Dagent.name=Deploy Agent -Dagent.ownPort=9091 -Dagent.work.dir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/work -Dant.home=/usr/share/ant -Dbuild.number=131 -Dbuild.vcs.number.Nutrino_Monitor_sources=588 -Dbuild.vcs.number.Nutrino_build_scripts=590 -Dfile.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 -Dfile.separator=/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp -Dos.arch=amd64 -Dos.name=Linux -Dos.version=3.5.0-19-generic -Dpath.separator=: -Dteamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=684 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9091/RPC2 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=45574 -Dteamcity.auth.password=mlTjdmhOxwfxuM6vGfcQPsKg81q29rFU -Dteamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=45574 -Dteamcity.build.changedFiles.file=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp/changedFiles7524737972530602224.txt -Dteamcity.build.checkoutDir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer -Dteamcity.build.id=45574 -Dteamcity.build.properties.file=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.build3049879068391711216.properties -Dteamcity.build.tempDir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp -Dteamcity.build.workingDir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer -Dteamcity.buildConfName=Deploy to Integration -Dteamcity.buildType.id=bt38 -Dteamcity.configuration.properties.file=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.config301718488736388101.properties -Dteamcity.projectName=Nutrition Builds -Dteamcity.runner.properties.file=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp/teamcity.runner1078243400245029410.properties -Dteamcity.runtime.props.file=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/agentTmp/ant7992360137092769527runtime -Dteamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/temp/buildTmp/testsToRunFirst5600043147441131768.txt -Dteamcity.version=7.1.2 (build 24170) -Dtomcat.server=integration -Duser.country=US -Duser.home=/home/system -Duser.language=en -Duser.name=system -Duser.timezone=Asia/Jerusalem -Dwork.dir=/home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer -classpath /usr/share/java/ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -lib /home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/plugins/antPlugin/ant-runtime.jar:/home/system/dev/TeamCity/buildDeployAgent/lib/runtime-util.jar -listener jetbrains.buildServer.agent.ant.AgentBuildListener -buildfile /home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer/build/deploy.xml deploy.nutrino.server
[15:06:21][Step 1/2] in directory: /home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer
[15:06:21][Step 1/2] taskdef
[15:06:21]
[taskdef] taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
[15:06:21]
[Step 1/2] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer/build/tomcat.tasks.xml:9: taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
[15:06:21][Step 1/2] Process exited with code 1
[15:06:21][Step 1/2] Ant output
[15:06:21][Ant output] Buildfile: /home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer/build/deploy.xml
[15:06:21][Ant output] 
[15:06:21][Ant output] BUILD FAILED
[15:06:21][Ant output] /home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer/build/deploy.xml:8: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[15:06:21][Ant output] /home/system/dev/TeamCity/Builds/DeployNutritionServer/build/tomcat.tasks.xml:9: taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask cannot be found
[15:06:21][Ant output]  using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
[15:06:21][Ant output] 
[15:06:21][Ant output] Total time: 0 seconds
[15:06:22][Step 1/2] Step Deploy (Ant) failed
```

Now, this is extremely weird, as when I run this from the command line it works perfectly:
ant -buildfile deploy.xml -Dtomcat.server= ...

There is no apparent difference between the two - running it from the CL and through the TC agent should both be running Ant from ANT_HOME (usr/share/ant), and loading the libraries in $ANT_HOME/lib.

Any help would be appreciated.
:)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `catalina-ant.jar` available in `$ANT_HOME/lib`? Otherwise, define a path element and add it to the `taskdef` element.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I put it in the bin instead...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering the question,

Thanks to @timomeinen - adding the catalina-ant.jar to $ANT_HOME/lib did the job.

Answer (score 0):

That means it is not seeing the lib catalina-ant.jar

You can add:

classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"
**classpath="C:\Programming\Tomcat\Instances\8080\lib\catalina-ant.jar"**

It will solve this reference problem, but I guess you will face similar problems in the future with other libraries, so in the long term you will still need solve the reference problem.